# Xamarin Forms (Android, IOS, UWP) - Get an unique device Id/Number

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

As I read, access to a serial number of device is no longer enabled for newer versions of Android and IOS devices. Because of that, I need to find a same unique alternative.

*When I was looking for it, the only thing I found is UUID for an android. The problem is that i don't have and idea and I can't find anything about how to access that info using a c#.*

**What I want to achieve is just to read an unique Id for android, IOS and UWP devices that can't be changed (like a serial number).**

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID

Comment: Create a Guid and persist it for the lifetime of the App being installed on the device.

Comment: Due to privacy concerns, it is deliberately no longer possible to uniquely identify a **device**. No app, regardless of technology, can do so, on newer OS versions. For one discussion of what you *can* do on Android, see [Best practices for unique identifier](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids). Like any platform-specific code, this goes in your `.Android` project. For each java class or method, the Xamarin c# equivalent usually has a very similar name (e.g. capitalize first letter). Or google `xamarin thejavanameyouarelookingfor` to find the equivalent doc.